# Remove yellow stains on toilet

Tags: toilet, cleaning

I have the following stains on my toilet

[image]

I tried to remove it with bleaching product but to no avail.

I was thinking of white vinegar but not sure if it would work as the surface is wet.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: If you end up going with a pumice stone or other abrasive medium, It will remove the stains, but will leave the surface with a rougher (but non-visible) finish resulting it making it easier in the future for stains to take hold, requiring more frequent cleaning.

Answer (score 3):

These appear to be rust stains.  I've had reasonable success with a product called Wink:

[Wink on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077W7PDJP)

there are also similar products that may be as effective but I have not tried them personally.  I do know that chlorine bleach does not work on these.

Be VERY careful with this product, however.  It contains HFl (hydrofluoric acid) which is nastier than HCl (hydrochloric acid).  Always follow the instructions carefully!

Comment: Yup, just used Wink to remove some coffee stains from a sink. Wondrous, stinky stuff!

Comment: hi @jwh20, these are not rust stains... more organic stains if you see where I'm coming to... would your solution works too?

Comment: HFl is a very reactive substance.  I would give it a try as it does seem to be effective on a wide swath of stains.

Answer (score 1):

Try scrubbing it with good old-fashioned comet and a stiff-bristled brush. Flush the toilet first, though, please.

Comment: I have a try, thank you @sam.